# Why do I get an error in the OpenCV code build part in GitHub Actions CI/CD?

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors

I know that GitAction is a server provided by Github, and I gave the command as below to build the server as an Open CV environment. I wonder if this is how it works. An error occurred on the build side. To run the code, I have to give the package download COMMAND as shown in the picture above to build the related library environment, right?
I would appreciate it if you could tell me why the build part didn't go well.

```
name: C++

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
          # Install minimal prerequisites (Ubuntu 18.04 as reference)
          sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y cmake g++ wget unzip
          # Download and unpack sources
      - name: Install OpenCV3.X
        run: |
          wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.0.zip
          unzip opencv.zip
          wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.0.zip
          sudo apt install libopencv-dev
      - name: unzip OpenCV3.X
        run: |
          mv opencv-3.4.0 opencv
          unzip opencv_contrib.zip
          mv opencv_contrib-3.4.0 opencv_contrib
      - name: build OpenCV3.X
        run: |   
          cd opencv
          mkdir build
          cd build
          cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
          -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
          -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
          -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
          -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
          -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
          -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
          make
          sudo make install
          sudo ldconfig
      - name: Run code test suite
        run: |
          chmod +x *.cpp
          chmod +x *.out
          echo "===== Testing started ====="
          ./a.out
          echo "===== Testing finished ====="
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ly1U.png)

https://github.com/Jlim01/git_test2
This is my github's repository occured action problem. You can see detail

In GitAction, the C++ code using the Opencv library is created with g++ and the object is executed. I want to use GitActions and I am new to GitActions.

Ps))
I found failed log but why next is proceed? If the any part in log is failed, then that time will break immediately..
I don't understand it haha
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axd2f.jpg)

Cmake failed is caused build error  right?
How to solve it?

Comment: It says "errors occurred" but your screenshot doesn't show the actual errors. Please edit your question with a *textual* and *complete* error log. I retagged your question since it has nothing to do with any of the tags you mentioned. (that I can see)

Comment: Hello I share my github that occured action problem.   repository is git_test2 
you can see simple code and action 
 https://github.com/Jlim01/git_test2